# How to print Array data retrieved from Database using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using cakePHP 1.26, and JQuery.

In a TestingController, I got this line of code

```
function testing(){
$r = $this->User->findallByuser_id(1);
}
```

and I am using JQuery Ajax to retrieve the data from function testing():

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: curl,   
      success: function(data){ 
      alert(data);  
      }
```

Here is the JQuery Alert output:

```
Array
```

And this is cakePHP output:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 50
            [name] => hello

        )
       ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, iterate it like an ordinary array:

```
for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++)
{
   alert(data[i]["user"]["id"]);
}
```

I suppose you will also need some template engine for JavaScript to perform easy HTML generation. Check [mustache.js](http://github.com/janl/mustache.js).